# Usage of httperf

Tags: networking, performance-testing, httperf

I had installed httperf on Fedora 21/Ubuntu 12.04 and tried to make a simple test with following command:

```
httperf --server www.google.com
```

It always gives me the following result:

```
httperf --client=0/1 --server=www.google.com --port=80 --uri=/ --send-buffer=4096 --recv-buffer=16384 --num-conns=1 --num-calls=1
httperf: can't open www.google.com
```

Do you have any ideas for this issue? Thanks!

PS

1. The Internet connection is good.
2. I had tried other sites and got the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Problem occures when you installing tool from sources. Instead use version from repository

```
apt-get install httperf
```

and it's will be work fine.